# Extract URL for Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have setup a website with recipes but in the process of migration OLD urls to NEW urls I'm facing issues with.

https://example.com/recipes/cheesy-baked-tacos/

This is my old URL structure and In a wordpress site I need to extract last part of the URL "cheesy-baked-tacos" and handle that in the template I use for recipes page.

Now when i click on the URL it goes to 404 page even though recipes page has setup.

I tried following htaccess rules but have no success

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^recipes/(.*)$ index.php?l=$1
```

Thanks in Advance.

Full htaccess file looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^recipes/(.*)$ index.php?l=$1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you enabled the RewriteEngine? To enable it you need to use **RewriteEngine on** at the top of the htaccess.

Comment: Your rule looks ok to me. What url are you going to?

Comment: that directs me to 404 page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix the issue with 301 Redirect. Here's what i used if it helps someone.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^recipes/(.*)$ recipe/?post_name=$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you should check your permalink change to starts with id to without query string
dont change htacces file
you just change permalink in new server
https://example.com/recipes/cheesy-baked-tacos/
this is your old url and has permalink set without query string 

new url https://example.com/recipes/cheesy-baked-tacos/id=50 just like
thats why your code have error
```

Comment: Nope we already have thousands of these OLD urls in our social media networks. We cannot update them one by one to include the id. I just need a way to automate this process.